# Motivation for Grassmannian variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, motivation, grassmannian

I need some information about the Grassmanian variety for my final project in algebraic geometry course that I am taking.

My questions are:

- Why do we define the Grassmannian variety?
- Do we use the Grassmannian variety for the construction of some other notions in algebraic geometry, if we do what are they?
- How we can go further by using the Grassmannian variety?

Comment: The books by Griffiths-Harris, Harris, and Eisenbud-Harris discuss a lot of applications of Grassmannians. Unfortunately they're all pretty demanding, but they do answer these questions and no one says you have to understand every word they write. To emphasize the role of Grassmannians: you use them to construct Hilbert schemes which in turn construct moduli spaces of curves. And these are some of the most important schemes around. I'll try to think of an elementary source later, but I do think an answer requires a source, unless someone is willing to write an article here.

Comment: To sketch the relation a little more: when you want to parametrize a set of varieties in a given projective space a natural thing to do is try to parametrize the corresponding ideals/equations, and these are vector subspaces of the polynomial ring. The first major problems with this approach are: (i) how do I reduce to working with finite dimensional vector spaces of equations? (ii) how do i make this work if my varieties don't have a preferred embedding into a projective space? On a simpler level, it helps you prove simple things like "the set of lines joining two varieties is a variety".